# Azure Table GetSharedAccessSignature endPartitionKey Parameter

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

Within the Azure SDK for .NET there is a [`GetSharedAccessSignature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.cloudtable.getsharedaccesssignature?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#overloads) that returns a shared access signature for a table:

```
public string GetSharedAccessSignature( 
  Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.SharedAccessTablePolicy policy, 
  string accessPolicyIdentifier, 
  string startPartitionKey, 
  string startRowKey, 
  string endPartitionKey, 
  string endRowKey);
```

Im curious about what does the `endPartitionKey` parameter means? I read about that if you not set it, all **subsequent** partitions are affected. But what are these subsequent partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Im curious about what does the endPartitionKey parameter means?

The parameters(startPartitionKey,startRowKey,endPartitionKey,endRowKey) allow us to specify a range of rows from (start PK, start RK) until (end PK, end RK).

For example, I have a table with 6 rows as following.

[image]

If I get SAS using following code. We can use this SAS to access the rows whose PartitionKey value must greater than P3 and less than P4.

```
string sas = table.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, null, "P3", null, "P4", null);
```

> I read about that if you not set it, all subsequent partitions are affected.

If we don't set the end PartitionKey parameter, all the rows whose PartitionKey value greater than P3 can be accessed using the return SAS.

```
string sas = table.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy, null, "P3", null, null, null);
```

Comment: Ahhh, I got it. Thank you Amor!